# Задание из учебника Мэтиза. Проблема рефакторинга

Tags: python

День добрый! Задание состоит в следующем:
метод fill_walk() получился слишком длинным. Создайте новый метод с именем get_step(), который определяет расстояние и направление для каждого шага,
после чего вычисляет этот шаг. В результате метод fill_walk() должен содержать два вызова get_step():

x_step = self.get_step()

y_step = self.get_step()

Рефакторинг сокращает размер fill_walk(), а метод становится более простым и понятным.

До него код работал, как надо, а после появилась ошибка:
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'**

Так как я только учусь программированию, то может что-то и упустил

```
from random import choice


class RandomWalk():
    """Класс для генерирования случайных блужданий."""
    def __init__(self, num_points=5000):
        """Инициализирует атрибуты блуждания."""
        self.num_points = num_points

        # Все блуждания начинаются с точки (0, 0).
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

    def fill_walk(self):
        """Вычисляет все точки блуждания."""
        # Шаги генерируются до достижения нужной длины.
        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
            x_step = self.get_step()
            y_step = self.get_step()
        
            # Отклонение нулевых перемещений.
            if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
                continue
        
            # Вычисление следующих значений x и y.
            x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step
          
            self.x_values.append(x)
            self.y_values.append(y)
                     
    def get_step(self):
        """Определение направления и длины перемещения."""
        x_direction = choice([-1, 1])
        x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
        x_step = x_direction * x_distance

        y_direction = choice([-1, 1])
        y_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
        y_step = y_direction * y_distance
```

Comment: А почему у вас метод `get_step` ничего не возвращает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно сказал @whistow в комментариях, вы забыли добавить `return` в методе `get_step()`. По умолчанию функции (и методы, само собой) возвращают None. В строке

```
x_step = self.get_step()
```

вы присваиваете переменной `x_step()` `None`, потому что этот метод ничего не возвращает. Далее, в строке

```
x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
```

вы конкатенируете число типа `int` с `None`, и это, естественно, производит ошибку TypeError. Добавьте оператор `return` в метод `get_step()` и все заработает!